# The requested operation failed

Tags: apache, windows, php, mysql

При запуске apache выдает ошибку: The requested operation failed.

В логе error.log появляется одна запись:

> [Wed May 11 18:16:46 2011] [warn] pid file D:/server/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Не подскажете, как устранить ошибку?﻿

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка может быть

1. из-за несовместимой версии PHP  (нужна VC6 x86 Thread Safe) - проверить версию;
2. из-за несовместимых расширений PHP (нужна mysql) - убрать лишнее.

Еще можно взять готовую сборку: XAMPP или WAMPP и не тратить время на настройку сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы его неправильно установили. Почитайте установку [тут](http://www.softtime.ru/article/index.php?id_article=95).

[Ссылка](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) на скачивание XAMPP.

Comment: Когда убираю строчки LoadModule php5_module "D:\server\php\php5apache2_2.dll" и PHPIniDir "D:\server\php\" из файла httpd.conf, тем самым отключаю поддержку php, то все нормально работает, подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, другая запущенная программа блокирует порт 80. Как правило, это Skype. Убрать галочку в настройках Skype, где указано, чтобы он использовал бы этот порт.